# how can I get LinkedIn group members

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api, members

I have been trying to get all the members of my LinkedIn groups. I have gone through their API's but LinkedIn don't support this.

I have tried many other ways of doing so through curl , different php functions, HTML DOM all have session problem (I am logged out every time). Then I tried to get members with iframe but iframe has cross domain restriction.

Is there any possible way of getting all the members of my groups in LinkedIn? I was thinking of proxy but I guess proxy solution will also fail due to sessions/cookies.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way to currently get all group members from the [Groups API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api). If you look through the available [Group Fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-fields), you can see there are no fields that are available that could be used to retrieve members.

Finally, from LinkedIn support themselves, [it's not possible](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/get-members-group).

Answer (score 0):

So you have a group-id and you want to display all the members in that group? Have you already established an oAuth connection? Can you post some API calls that you're currently using?

Maybe this will help (see "Retrieving a Group's Profile Details")
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#profiledetails

Comment: Thanks Adam for your quick response. Yes i have the group id i can get it through linkedin group API(Get group i am a member of) and Yes i have established oAuth connection and i have been trying all the group APIs. And about "Retrieving a Group's Profile Details" API still i am unable to get the members of that group.

Comment: Oh I thought you were the group admin.... hmmm I'd be surprised if you could get the whole member list if you are only an authenticated member yourself. Linkedin are quite strict on privacy (unlike the Twitter). Also I *think* you can only pull data from members who are only 1/2/3 steps away from your own profile. So you probably couldn't get the whole list anyway. Post back if you find a solution though as it will help others. Good luck!